# 1 button with 2 x partial refresh and a document save

Tags: xpages

I would like to do 2 Partial refreshes and 1 document save with the onclick of 1 button.
How could I do this ?
What I tried so far :

1. In CCJS , and no sumbmission to the server

   ```
   XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:PanelSubitem}", {
       onComplete: function() {
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:PanelSubsubitem}", {
                onComplete: function() { 
               '#{javascript:document1.save()}';
               }
           });
       }
   });
   ```

   Result: The 2 refrehes work but the document save not (normal since you can't acces the back-end with ccjs.
2. Put the same code in SSJS, with a partial refesh or with a full refresh

   Result: First click on button refreshes first Panel and then stops. Second refresh will update the second Panel and stops. Third click on the button will save the document. (this is also normal since the partial or full refresh of the code conflicts with the partial or full refresh of the server option, since you can only do 1 refresh at a time)

So if I can't do it in SSJS and I can't do it in CSJS , how can I do it ?

Comment: Is the **order** of events you describe (PR1, PR2, Save) of importance? Or could an order of Save, PR1, PR2 work as well?

Comment: The order is important. It has to be PR1 PR2 save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is to create a Save button which saves the document and partial refreshes itself after completion of second partial refresh via CSJS. So your snippet would be something like this:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:PanelSubitem}", {
   onComplete: function() {
      XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:PanelSubsubitem}", {
         onComplete: function() { 
            document.getElementById("#{id:btnSave}").click();
         }
      });
   }
});
<xp:button value="Save" id="btnSave">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="btnSave">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.save()}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

You can hide the Save button using CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about CSS. How do I hide this button with CSS ?

Comment: EDIT : Meanwhile I found out how to hide
Thank you for your suggestion. It works this way, but it's of course a way around the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:actionGroup>
                    <xp:executeScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:document.save();}]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:executeScript>
                </xp:actionGroup>
            </xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[(function(){
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:PanelSubItem}");
            XSP.allowSubmit();
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:PanelSubSubItem}");
          })();]]>
       </xp:this.onComplete>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: You can use immediately invoked function to invoke the partial refreshes and then use execute the save function within the script tags as above. XSP.allowSubmit allow you to use multiple ids.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to take advantage of the fact that you can run CSJS followed by SSJS. SSJS will only run of CSJS returns true.

So for your button you add your existing double partial refresh code as client-side code to the onClick event of the button (and perhaps you need to add a `return true` statement as well), and then you add your document save code as SSJS to the same onClick event.

Comment: Per, Thank you for your reply. Since I have to run the CSJS code with no submission to the server , I can't add a SSJS anymore. About the return true statement; How do I add this in this case ?

Comment: Why with no submission? If you want to refresh and save, then you have to submit something to the server at some point.

Comment: I would just add the "return true" statement at the end of the CSJS logic. Remember that the SSJS code is only executed if the CSJS goes well (returns true). So nothing will be submitted until after the CSJS code has run

Comment: Per I just tried the following. I've put the code above to CSJS + return true at the end (without the SSJS).I also added an alert message after every step . The first allert I get is before the return true.Second alert after the PanelRefresh1 and third alert after the PanelRefresh2 . Why do I get first the alert I've put before the return true ?

Comment: After that I added the SSJS to save the document and as server option full refresh. Then I get aprox. the same happens as if I put all the code in SSJS. First time click I get the alert message I've put before the "return true" and only the first panel refreshes.No additional alert messages ... ?

Comment: Then I click a second time and again I get the message I've put before the "return true" and Panel2 refreshes.No additional messages ...